# Line pattern fill in legend symbology- QGIS 2.18

Tags: polygon, symbology, distance, legend, qgis-2.18

I work with "line pattern fill" in polygon layer with distance value: 5

[image]
[image]

and the legend is:

[image]

My problem is when i choose value 20 in the distance option- the green line disappear from the symbology legend.

[image]

How can i choose distance value 20 and still the green line will be presented in the legend? i know one solution by draw a green line in the legend by myself, but i looking for a smart automatic solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the legend's symbol are drawn depending of the scale of the linked map.
To solve that kind of issues I create a second map outside of the composition (so it will not appear on the image) and I link my legend to this map which has a scale that fit with the displaying legend

[image: legend]

Comment: nice solution, but  i seek for an automatic solution in the fisrt map legend.

Comment: Ok, after searching a lot about that, i never find better solution than this one... But for me it's quite automatic because when you have defined your secondary map and link the legend. You can do every changes you want on your main map without affecting your legend.